# Show a collinearity in a tetrahedron

Tags: geometry

**my question**

Let $ABCD$ be a tetrahedron and the means $M, N$ of the edges $AC$ and $BD$, respectively.
Show that for any point $P$ on the segment $MN$, with P different from M and N, there exist and are unique
the points $X$ and $Y$ on the segments $AB$, respectively $CD$, so that $X, P$ and $Y$ are collinear.

**my idea**

[image]

Because P is different from M and N if
$X, Y, P$ are collinear, wich means X does not belong to ${A, B}$ and so on
$Y$ does not belong to ${C, D}$.
Indeed, if $X = A$, then
$XY ⊂ (ACD)$, so $P ∈ (ACD)$, false. The other situations are similar.

That all I could think of. Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let S be the mean of AD and T the mean of BC. From the triangle ADC we have SM||DC. From the triangle BDC we have NT||DC. It means that SM||NT. And there is a plane SMTN.

Now the problem became the following. We have a plane (SMTN), a line in it (MN) with a point in it (P), two lines parallel to the plane (AB, DC). Such that neither of three lines a parallel to each other. We want to prove that there are unique points X in DC and Y in AB such that X-P-Y.

Let $\alpha$ be a plane containing DC and parallel to SMTN. When X runs through AB, line XP intersects with $\alpha$. (If it doesn’t intersect then it is parallel to $\alpha$. Then since it contains P, it is in SMTN. Then there is a point of AB in SMTN, but they are parallel). The set of intersection points is some line in $\alpha$, parallel to AB. So it is not parallel to CD and has a unique intersection with it. That would be point Y.

Notice that intersection of AP with $\alpha$ and intersection of BP with $\alpha$ are in different half-planes of $\alpha$ with respect to DC.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer. May I ask what you wanted to say in this fragment ,,When Y runs through AB, line YP intersects with α
. (If it doesn’t intersect then it is parallel to α
. Then since it contains P, it is in SMTN. Then there is a point of AB in SMTN, but they are parallel)."? Can you be more explicit, as I don't understand it?

Comment: to be honest, both of them...

Comment: @IONELABUCIU We take any point Y in AB, draw a line YP. It intersects with the plane $\alpha$ in some point X. Then we take another point Y’ in AB, draw a line Y’P, it intersects with $\alpha$ in X’. And so on. After we took all the Y points in AB, the X points formed a line in $\alpha$.

Comment: oooo... i undersatnd now. If you look in the problem I wrote that $x\in AB, y\in DC$ and you took them opposite, which made no sense in my drawing. But still, why the set of intersection points is some line in α, parallel to AB? What do you mean by the set of intersection points?

Comment: @IONELABUCIU Yes, I confused X and Y, sorry. I will continue to be confused though to be consistent. Take points Y, Y’ in AB. PY, PY’ meet $\alpha$ at X, X’ respectively. The intersection of the planes YY’P and $\alpha$ is the line XX’ in $\alpha$. This line is parallel to AB, due to a standard school fact.

Comment: which is the standard school fact?

Comment: @IONELABUCIU If a line $\ell$ is parallel to a plane $\beta$ and we draw a plane $\gamma$ through a line $\ell$ such that $\beta\not\parallel\gamma$, then the line of intersection of $\beta$ and $\gamma$ is parallel to $\ell$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ \vec{b} = \vec{AB} , \vec{c} = \vec{AC}, \vec{d} = \vec{AD} $

And let $A$ be the origin.  Then

$M = t \vec{c} , N = \vec{b} + s (\vec{d} - \vec{b} ) $

Now, since $P$ is on the line segment connecting $M$ and $N$, then

$ P = (1 - w) M + w N = (1 - w) t \vec{c} + w \bigg( (1 - s) \vec{b} + s \vec{d} \bigg) \tag{1}$

Let $X$ be on the line segment $AB$, then

$ X = \alpha \vec{b} $

And let $Y$ be on the line segment $CD$, then

$ Y = (1 - \beta) \vec{c} + \beta \vec{d} $

Since we want $P$ to lie on the line segment connecting $X$ and $Y$, then we must able to express $P$ as follows

$ P = (1 - \gamma) X + \gamma Y = (1 - \gamma) \alpha \vec{b} + \gamma \bigg( (1 - \beta) \vec{c} + \beta \vec{d} \bigg) \tag{2}$

Comparing $(1)$ and $(2)$, and since $\vec{b}, \vec{c}, \vec{d}$ are linearly independent, then equality of the two expressions implies:

$ w(1 - s) = (1 - \gamma) \alpha $

$ (1 - w) t = \gamma (1 - \beta) $

$ w s = \gamma \beta $

Adding the last two equations

$ (1 - w) t + w s = \gamma $

It follows that

$ \beta = \dfrac{ w s }{ (1 - w) t + w s } $

and

$ \alpha = \dfrac{ w(1 - s) }{ 1 - (1 - w) t - w s } $

It can be easily shown that $ 0 \lt \alpha , \beta, \gamma \lt 1 $

Therefore, for all points $P$, specified by any valid choice of $t,s,w$ we can find unique $\alpha, \beta $ that in turn specify the points $X$ and $Y$.